# stabilizing a sequence shot that moves along a path

Tags: davinci-resolve, tracking

which is the best method for stabilizing a Ronin hand held sequence shot that moves along a path? I'm using DaVinci Resolve and Blender.

Comment: just to clarify as its not 100% clear. you want to stabilize a shot made on a drone? if that's not what you're trying to do then please provide more details :)

Comment: It's an hand held sequence, walking between two walls, with nobody in front of it, so I don't have any  clear target to follow, everything is passing, I imagine I should search for averaging many different stabilization paths.

Comment: in the inspector tab of DaVinci Resolve in the edit page, if you scroll down you should see a stabilization tab, under it, there are a bunch of options you can use to stabilize your clip. play around with the settings or you could watch some YouTube tutorials about it. I would link some good ones but I'm unable to access YouTube at the moment. if that doesn't work you can try blender and ask on the blender stack exchange website for better answers. hope that helps.